# парсинг объекта в json файле

Tags: python, json

Есть следующий json файл, вставлю только кусочек по которому есть вопрос

```
"objects": [
    {
      "address": {
        "fullAddress": "1"
      },
      "guid": "1",
      "name": "«1»",
      "region": {
        "name": "1",
        "code": "1"
      },
      "xsdData": {
        "shortName": "«2»",
        "City": "2",
        "Email": "2",
        "numberFederalList": "2",
        "Phone": "2",
        "SiteUrl": "2",
        "View": "2",
        "Fax": "",
        "ClassificationInformation": {
          "categoryStars": "три звезды",
          "InfoAccredOrganization": {
            "accredOrganization": "2",
            "accredOrganizationNumber": "2",
            "accredOrganizationShortName": "2",
            "specialist1": "2"
          },
          "order": {
            "dateEnd": "2",
            "licenseDateIssued": "2",
            "licenseNumber": "2"
          }
        },
        "InformationRooms": [
          {
            "InformationRoomsBlock": {
              "numberRooms": "182",
              "numberSeats": "304",
              "roomCategory": "Первая"
            }
          },
          {
            "InformationRoomsBlock": {
              "numberRooms": "1",
              "numberSeats": "4",
              "roomCategory": "Высшая \"апартамент\""
            }
          },
          {
            "InformationRoomsBlock": {
              "numberRooms": "1",
              "numberSeats": "2",
              "roomCategory": "Высшая \"сюит\""
            }
          },
          {
            "InformationRoomsBlock": {
              "numberRooms": "15",
              "numberSeats": "30",
              "roomCategory": "Высшая \"люкс\""
            }
          },
          {
            "InformationRoomsBlock": {
              "numberRooms": "3",
              "numberSeats": "6",
              "roomCategory": "Высшая \"джуниор сюит\""
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
```

Мне нужно вытаскивать `numberRooms` и `numberSeats` из этой части. При этом нужно чтобы при выводе эти переменные по разному назывались (в зависимости от `roomCategory`).

Вот что я смог написать

```
for record in json_data:   /массив по всему `json` файлу
 for add in record.get('objects', {}):
              for i in add['xsdData'].get('InformationRooms', {}):
                roomCategory = ['InformationRoomsBlock'][i]['roomCategory']
                if roomCategory == "Высшая \"сюит\"":
                    numberRooms_suit = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberRooms', '')
                    numberSeats_suit = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberSeats', '')
                elif roomCategory == "Первая":
                    numberRooms_first = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberRooms', '')
                    numberSeats_first = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberSeats', '')
                    print(numberSeats_first)
                elif roomCategory == "Первая для МГН":
                    numberRooms_mgn = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberRooms', '')
                    numberSeats_mgn = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberSeats', '')
                    print(numberSeats_mgn)
```

Смысл в том что я записываю из `json` файла `roomCategory` в переменную и проверяю.
Данный код работает на 1-2 записях (тестил), но записей намного больше и если я запускаю на большом `json` файле, то получаю ошибку

```
roomCategory = ['InformationRoomsBlock'][i]['roomCategory']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли это как-то пофиксить. А возможно я просто неправильно делаю цикл чтобы добраться до нужных строчек в `json`.

Answer (score 0):

В объявлении roomCategory намудрили, вам интерпретатор ругается что в качестве индекса для списка вы пытаетесь передать строку вместо числа.

Должно быть так:

```py
roomCategory = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('roomCategory', None)
```